# How to guarantee exclusive access when modifying network adapter properties

Tags: c#-4.0, concurrency, wmi

I am using WMI's Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class, EnableStatic method to set static IPs of a Loopback network adapter for testing.  I noticed that the OS takes out a lock when there's a visible property sheet.  When user dismisses the sheet with changes, things freeze up until the update has completed.

How can I ensure exclusive access between my program in C# and Windows UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `EnableStatic` method of the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class already acquires an exclusive lock to change the network adapter settings. A microsoft knowledge base article lead me to this conclusion [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950134/en-us/).
There is also a COM interface called `INetCfgLock` you could use to acquire an exclusive lock for changing network adapter settings. To acquire the lock use the `INetCfgLock::AcquireWriteLock` method.

BEGIN EDIT:

Here is a link to the project on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/adapterlist.aspx?msg=3108641) which shows the use of the `INetCfgLock` COM interface and the `INetCfgLock::AcquireWriteLock` in C#.

END EDIT

Hope, this helps.

Comment: On the topic of inference: it sounds as though after the fix EnableStatic is no longer taking out a lock, just so that the user app won't crash.

Comment: @GregC: I've updated my answer with a link to a codeproject C# sample.

Comment: @CregC: Don't know whether or not they removed the lock. They could also handle the error code in some way.

Comment: @GregC: What do you mean by low quality? W hat kind of quality do you exprxt? What is acceptabel for you?

Comment: I am looking for code that can behave well in presence of an exception, and that passes most if not all FxCop suggestions.