# Changing IP address using ManagementObjects: incorrect IP address / locking issue?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-10, wmi

So I'm attempting to change the IP address on the host system programmatically using the ManagementObjects classes and I'm attempting to change it using the *Microsoft generated* code as follows:

```
public static void SetIPAddress()
{
    try
    {
        ManagementObject classInstance =
                new ManagementObject("root\\cimv2",
                "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index='15'",
                null);

        // Obtain in-parameters for the method
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = classInstance.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
        // I tried both of these, but neither seem to work
        //inParams["IPAddress"] = new string [] { "10", "13", "42", "1" };
        //inParams["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { "255", "255", "255", "0" };
        inParams["IPAddress"] = new string[] { "10.13.42.1" };
        inParams["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { "255.255.255.0" };


        // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", inParams, null);

        // List outParams
        Console.WriteLine("Out parameters:");
        Console.WriteLine("ReturnValue: " + outParams["ReturnValue"]);
    }
    catch (ManagementException err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while trying to execute the WMI method: " + err.Message);
    }
}
```

I'm getting two different error codes (depending on the IPAddres/Subnet mask setup).

Using the formatting:

```
inParams["IPAddress"] = new string[] { "10.13.42.1" };
inParams["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { "255.255.255.0" };
```

I get [Error Code 2147786788](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572):

> Write lock not enabled. For more information, see INetCfgLock::AcquireWriteLock.

I have a lock using that exact lock method as [supplied here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682857/how-to-guarantee-exclusive-access-when-modifying-network-adapter-properties).

Using the second formatting (`"10", "13", "42", "1"`) I get:

[Error code 70](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/enablestatic-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration#return-value):

> Invalid IP Address

See [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) for a full list of error codes

Or is there another way I can programmatically change the IP Address (I need to change it according to its enumerated name, which will always be the same - it just so happens that the name matches index 15 on this machine.)

Edit: If you'd like to try it, theres [a WMI code generate here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572).

Edit  2: I tried [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/softwaresimian/2014/09/10/setting-an-ip-to-address-to-be-static-and-then-dynamic-in-c/) solution too, but I would get the same `2147786788`.

Comment: If someone wants, they can see my "lock" implementation (theres not much of it).

Comment: Credit to @Uwe Keim for the edits

Comment: Please [do _not_ add tags to question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: It's not a tag, it's a part of the description. Win32 can also be accessed using other languages. If you feel like its a tag, remove it, but I disagree.

Comment: Weirdly enough if you access this through powershell (NetAdapter/NetAdapterConfiguration) it works easily and can be done with one liners.